# Generating UUIDs is not working with Symfony 5.3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, uuid

I want to generate IDs for new entites in the RFC 4122 format (f.e. c9bb9b5a-2950-4f02-a9df-3925a0b62513)

https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/components/uid.html#generating-ulids
https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineBundle/current/custom-id-generators.html

I tried it first with my own IdGenerator class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

class IdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $uuid = Uuid::v4();
        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="App\Service\IdGenerator")
 */
private $id;
```

I debugged it with XDebug. It got into the correct class and function, created and returned the correct UUID but then I still get the same errors when I try to load my fixtures:

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO step (id, text, periodically, necessary, activated, created_at, modified_at, created_b  
  y, modified_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["\x2b\x06\x41\x56\x73\xb0\x4f\xd2\x80\xfa\xa2\x87\xd1\xed\x31\x5f", "ste  
  p1", 0, 0, 1, "2022-02-12 23:35:58", "2022-02-12 23:35:58", "housemeister-system", "housemeister-system"]:                                 
                                                                                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xB0O\xD2\x80\xFA\xA2...' for column 'id' at row 1
```

Somehow it still tries to insert it as binary.

My second attempt was to generate it manually in the constructor of the entity:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $uuid = Uuid::v4()->__toString();
    $this->id = $uuid;
}
```

Same result, same error messages. Anyone got an idea?

EDIT:
Recently updated doctrine in my Symfony 5.3 project. It seems that this updated changed the id type from char(36) to binary(16). Maybe that context info helps.

Comment: Did you create the field manually in the database? Uuids are not really strings, they are 128bit numbers. MySQL didn't add a native type until relatively recently, so before it was a 16-byte binary field; doctrine still uses it for compatibility. Try deleting the field and creating it with a migration or `bin/console doctrine:schema:update`.

Comment: Ok, do:mi:di reveals, that it would like to change my ids from char(36) to binary(16). I would like to prevent that somehow, because all the data on the prod DB uses the char36 uuids. I recently updated doctrine in my symfony project, so that must have triggered that somehow.

Comment: As I said, for compatibility, `uuid` on MySQL/MariaDB is mapped as a BINARY(16), and always has been. If you are dead set on using a string, then don't declare the `type="uuid"`, but `type="text", length=36`. I wouldn't recommend it, though: data and indexes for the field will be bigger, unique checks more expensive, depending on your database size you might need to tweak your memory, etc. Or you might want to implement your own type to take care of the conversion from string to `Uuid`.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue, and I fix it with :

```
composer require ramsey/uuid-doctrine
```